# Plotly API using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, plotly

I was wondering how to go about making a basic single dataset Plotly REST call using google apps scripts. Could someone please provide just a basic function that does this? It would greatly help me, and will try and help those in the future who help me. I think I'm getting hung up on adding the dataset. This what I have so far:

Let dataSet be a (nx2) array in the form [[date0, r0], [date1, r1], ..., [daten, rn]] s.t. date0 > daten and ri in the reals.

```
function plot(dataSet){

  var key = "XXXXXXXXXX";
  var url = "https://plot.ly/clientresp";
  var un = "un=XXXXXXX";
  var origin = "origin=plot";
  var platform = "platform=lisp";

  ...

  return plotlyUrlImage;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `UrlFetchApp.fetch` and specify it to be a `post` request.

```
function plot(dataSet){
  var key = "XXXXXXXXXX";
  var url = "https://plot.ly/clientresp";
  var un = "XXXXXX";
  var origin = "plot";
  var platform = "lisp";

  var payload = {
    "un": un,
    "key": key,
    "origin": origin,
    "platform": platform,
    "args": JSON.stringify(args),
    "kwargs": JSON.stringify(kwargs)
  };

  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "payload": payload
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var rs = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  return rs["url"];
}
```

Reference:

- [UrlFetchApp.fetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [plotly response](https://plot.ly/rest/)

Comment: Yes! Works like a charm! As soon as I get my rep up I'll vote up. Everyone please vote up for the above. Thank you!